# LORA VS NRF24L01

Tags: smart-home, lora

I want to chooses between nrf24l01 and lora-ra02 for my smart home project The following parameters are very important to me

- distance range (covering an area of 400 square meters)
- Ability to cross hard objects
- life time
- Build quality

Comment: How much range do you need?

Comment: @Helmar : Can cover a home with a maximum area of 400 Square meters

Comment: Please add some more information about that via [edit]. The shape of the area is rather important when talking about square meters.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144358/wireless-home-automation-2-4ghz-versus-433mhz)

Comment: @Helmar The shape of the area is not very important just say approximately.

Comment: So it's a square and approximately 20m is the max distance?

Comment: easily done with 2.4ghz...

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this [well-written article here](https://www.upswift.io/post/nrf24-vs-lora-for-wireless-communication-between-iot-devices) by upswift.io. Below is a summary of some of the major points that might be helpful for your decision:

---

**--------- NRF24L01 Module: ---------**

- **Range:** 800m (depends on other factors such as transmit power, antenna quality, obstacles in path).
- **Operating band:** 2.4GHz ISM band
- **Operating voltage:** 3.3V
- **Operating current:** 11-14 mA
- **Data transfer rate:** 2Mbps

**--------- SX1278 LoRa Module: ---------**

- **Range:** 10km (depends on other factors such as transmit power, antenna quality, obstacles in path).
- **Operating band:** 137MHz to 525MHz ISM band
- **Operating voltage:** 1.8-3.7 V
- **Operating current:** 10-120 mA
- **Data transfer rate:** 37.5kbps

---

Thus the major advantage of LoRa here is the much higher range; and for the NRF24 it is the much higher data transfer rate. Both should work well given your parameters of interest but **if you want a quick selection for your question** then I'd suggest the NRF24L01 because it is cheaper and has relatively more information and tutorials on it at the time of this answer.

You may also be interested in other factors such as full-duplex support or low power performance. These are discussed a bit in the [article](https://www.upswift.io/post/nrf24-vs-lora-for-wireless-communication-between-iot-devices).

Comment: Of course 10 km is outside with line of sight between devices. Indoors it can be much less, closer to a few hundred meters or even a few dozen depending on construction.